# Error In Gradle AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Error:A problem occurred configuring root project '2. Full Source Code'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.0.0-alpha9.
>        Required by:
>            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha9
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.0.0-alpha9.
>   inconsistent module metadata found. Descriptor: com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha9 Errors: bad module name: expected='gradle-core' found='gradle'

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha9'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following line to your project/build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
```

**project/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.jar
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.jar
Required by:
    project :

Comment: try clean &  build, wait till build completes successfully. It may take time to download gradle zip first time